# Xampp is not working properly in ubuntu13.04

Tags: 13.04, apache2, mysql, xampp

I am new to ubuntu operating system and i tried the xampp installation process like the following  steps..

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo mkdir -p /opt
sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz -C /opt
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

After xampp start it is showing the following message

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Another FTP daemon is already running.
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

How can i solve this problem. Any suggestions are acceptable...

Comment: Please do not abuse/confuse lamp for xamp :-)

Comment: @Rinzwind ok..got it...